# How do I make multiple lines inside a .json file with JSON.simple?

Tags: java, json

This might be a very silly one but I'd like to know how I can create a json file that looks like this:

```
{
  "aString":"foo",
  "anArray":
  [
    "foo",
    "bar",
    "obj"
  ],
  "anInteger":100
}
```

instead of this: `{"aString":"foo","anArray":["foo","bar","obj"],"anInteger":100}`

Here's the code that creates the second one:

```
public class Main
{
    public static final String defDir = "C:\\Users\\*UserName*\\Desktop\\Java\\Test\\src\\Files\\";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("aString", "foo");
        obj.put("anInteger", 100);

        JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
        list.add("foo");
        list.add("bar");
        list.add("obj");

        obj.put("anArray", list);

        try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter(defDir + "test.json"))
        {
            file.write(obj.toString());
            file.flush();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And how do I read multiple-line json with JSON.simple

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `obj.toString(4)` to indent with 4 spaces for example. JSONObject has a overloaded `toString()` method which accepts indent parameter which in turn pretty print the JSON.

From the [Javadocs](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString-int-). Here I am quoting for your reference.

`public java.lang.String toString(int indentFactor) throws JSONException`

> Make a prettyprinted JSON text of this JSONObject.
>   Warning: This method assumes that the data structure is acyclical.
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> **indentFactor** - The number of spaces to add to each level of indentation.
>
> **Returns**:
>   a printable, displayable, portable, transmittable representation of the object, beginning with { (left brace) and ending with } (right brace).

Comment: It looks like I haven't got this method, I get the compile error "cant reolve method"

Comment: From which library you are importing JSONObject?

Comment: org.json.simple.JSONObject

Comment: Then looks like that library doesn't support that method. Use the library I have mentioned you should be fine.

Comment: So I don't even need JsonSimple? Java already has a deafault lib for that?? thx!!

Comment: Good :) Kindly accept answer if it works for you :)

Comment: Or not, because the autocomplete doesn't give me the JSONObject...

Comment: You can add dependency in pom file.

Comment: What is a pom file?